# How to deal with a property memory management in IOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

in my app, I have an IBAction method to change view to a another view :

```
-(IBAction)beginGame:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"beginGame clicked");
    GameView * thisGameView = [[[GameView alloc] init];
    MainAppDelegate * delegate = (MainAppDelegate *) [[ UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    delegate.window.rootViewController = thisGameView;
}
```

How should I deal with rootViewController property and thisGameView memory management?
release thisGameView now?

Please fill me some code in this 'beginGame' method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should release `thisGameView` after assigning it to `delegate.window.rootViewController`. The assignment will retain it.

Answer (score 1):

If `rootViewController` property is a retain property, so you can release `thisGameView` instance after the line:

```
delegate.window.rootViewController = thisGameView;
```

Comment: very thanks, I found rootViewController is retain: @property(nonatomic,retain) UIViewController *rootViewController __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);  // default is nil

Comment: That's what I told you in my answer. :)